# Get coordinates of a Bitmap image from an ImageView twice as small

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) containing a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) image. The image is twice as big as its container. I have declared `onScroll()` to be able to move around the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) image. How can I get the coordinates of the [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) on the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) image?

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
_iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
_iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
_iv.setMaxHeight(bm.getHeight());
_iv.setMaxWidth(bm.getWidth());
_iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

Bitmap newBm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, bm.getWidth() * 2, bm.getHeight() * 2, true);
_iv.setImageBitmap(newBm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an actual way to do this. Here's the method I've used:

Upon creating the [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), scroll to a known location.

```
int ivX = 0;
int ivY = 0;

_iv.invalidate();
_iv.scrollTo(ivX, ivY);
```

This way I have the exact (x, y) coordinates of where I am. Then, I've implemented the [onScroll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onScroll%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float%29) method and used the generated distances to recalculate my (x, y) coordinates:

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    //Add the scroll distance to the old X, Y coordinates
    ivX += distanceX;
    ivY += distanceY;

    //Scroll to the new location
    _iv.scrollTo(ivX, ivY);

    return false;
} //End onScroll()
```

In addition, to get a better understanding of how `scrollTo()` works and the relationship between the coordinates of the image and its container, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773206/where-does-android-view-scrolltox-y-scroll-to/7851835#7851835) to a different post of mine.