# Where does Android View.scrollTo(x, y) scroll to?

Tags: android, android-view, android-scroll

[`scrollTo(int x, int y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) says:

> x the x position to scroll to
>
> y the y position to scroll to

[`onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> l Current horizontal scroll origin.
>
> t Current vertical scroll origin.

What I would like to know and can't find anywhere, is where is x,y? Top left? Center? I tried a few tests and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

After extensive research and testing I've finally understood how [scrollTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) works.

`(0,0)` are the coordinates to the top left corner of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) container. When scrolling to any `(x,y)` point, the top left corner of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) will be placed at the `(x,y)` coordinates.

If the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) is showing an image, [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), larger than the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) itself, scrolling to `(0,0)` will place the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) in the center of the image. This way, the top left corner of the image will be located at `(-dX/2, -dY/2)` and the bottom right corner at `(mW - dX/2, mH - dY/2)`. `dX` represents the difference between the widths of the image and the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html). And `dY` represents the difference between the heights of the image and the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html).

In order to see the bottom right corner and not go passed it (lower or further to the right), this is the proper call: `scrollTo(mW - ivW - dX/2, mH - ivH - dY/2);`

The attached image shows the graphical representation of the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) and Bitmap image positioning.

[image: Graphical representation of the relationship between the image and the view.]

Comment: I have a question now... That depends on the gravity of the View, am i wrong? If i set the gravity to "top" the Bitmap should be aligned to the top of the ImageView?

Comment: I haven't tested that. But, because the size of the Bitmap is larger than the actual View, the alignment shouldn't influence it. Let me know if you test it and what are the results.

Answer (score 1):

From [`getX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getX%28%29):

> The visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to
>   the translationX property plus the current left property.

For `getY()` it's from top. So (0,0) is top left.

I don't know if `scrollTo()` takes into account the `translationX` property, because it's "recent" and I haven't been coding for a while, but I'd bet it does.