# TextView scrolling automatically

Tags: android, textview

When I have TextView example:

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);

tx.setId( Integer.parseInt(touched) );
tx.setX(X);
tx.setY(Y);
tx.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
tx.setTextSize(25);
tx.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EF7620"));
tx.setShadowLayer(16.5f, 0, 0, Color.parseColor("#EF7620"));
tx.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
```

I make some events and manipulation in this tx TextView, but this is not important. Only i want to do is, that I want to scroll or move this TextView somwhere when other event ends.

For example:

[image]

The only solution I found is [scrollTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773206/where-does-android-view-scrolltox-y-scroll-to), but did not worked for me

```
tx.scrollTo(100, 100);
```

Comment: I think it depends on how the TextView is inserted in the "dashboard". I think you should use a RelativeLayout container to get scrollTo() working

Comment: Thanks for answer. I exactly use RelativeLayout as container of my TextView. The whole bad thing is that when i use scrollTo, happens nothing, no error, no exception, no success...

Comment: this could help: http://android-er.blogspot.it/2011/09/scroll-view-scrollby-and-scrollto.html (Let me know)