# ScrollView ScrollBy method takes 2 parameters

Tags: android, methods, scrollview

ScrollView layout is actually a vertical scroller.

Why the scroll view method takes x parameter while it only scrolls vertically?

Shouldn't it take only the y parameter? since the x parameter is useless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code comes from `ScrollView.class`.
`ScrollView` need to call `View`'s `scrollTo(x, y)`, so it takes 2 parameters.
Therefore, any `View`'s subclass, including `ScrollView`, can scroll by x axis and y axis.

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    // we rely on the fact the View.scrollBy calls scrollTo.
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        x = clamp(x, getWidth() - mPaddingRight - mPaddingLeft, child.getWidth());
        y = clamp(y, getHeight() - mPaddingBottom - mPaddingTop, child.getHeight());
        if (x != mScrollX || y != mScrollY) {
            super.scrollTo(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Then why `ScrollView` only scrolls in vertical direction?
Look at `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method in `ScrollView`.
It only handles `ev.getY()` !
On the other hand, `HorizonalScrollView` only handles `ev.getX()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the scroll view method takes x parameter while it only scrolls
>   vertically?

This is only the case if your layout file is the same width as your view. Take a look at [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773206/where-does-android-view-scrolltox-y-scroll-to)

You can also scroll horizontaly using `HorizontalScrollView`, there you will need the x parameter. Check [the developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) for this.

Or you can use this two dimensional scroller shown in [this blog](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/) to make use of the both of the parameters if needed.